# Installing lampp on ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Tags: mysql, apache, ubuntu, lamp, lampp

I am trying to install lamp on ubuntu 14.04 LTS. After installing, I did

```
sudo su
/opt/lampp/lampp start
```

It gives me this error :

> Starting XAMPP for Linux 5.6.8-0...  XAMPP: Starting Apache...fail. 
>   XAMPP: Another web server is already running.  XAMPP: Starting
>   mySQL...ok.

How do I make Apache work and what could be that another web server already running?

Comment: Run `netstat -tlpn` as root to see what servers are running, and look for something on a web-server port (e.g. 80 for http, or 443 for https). But be aware that using `/opt/` instead of distro packages is poorly supported.

Answer (score 1):

```
sidra@sidra-7G-Series:~$ sudo /opt/lampp/lampp start
```

Starting XAMPP for Linux 5.6.8-0...

XAMPP: Starting Apache...fail.

XAMPP:  Another web server is already running.

XAMPP: Starting MySQL...ok.

XAMPP: Starting ProFTPD...already running.

sidra@sidra-7G-Series:~$ sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 stop

- Stopping web server 
  apache2                                                                                                                   * 
  sidra@sidra-7G-Series:~$ sudo /opt/lampp/lampp start

Starting XAMPP for Linux 5.6.8-0...

XAMPP: Starting Apache...ok.

XAMPP: Starting MySQL...ok.

XAMPP: Starting ProFTPD...already running.

Comment: "sidra@sidra-7G-Series:~$ sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 stop

    Stopping web server apache2 * sidra@sidra-7G-Series:~$ sudo /opt/lampp/lampp start

Comment: Yea i get the following output  Starting XAMPP for Linux 5.6.8-0...

XAMPP: Starting Apache...ok.

XAMPP: Starting MySQL...ok.

XAMPP: Starting ProFTPD...already running.   But in the xampp window I still see the red circle beside mysql. (Stopped is seen beside it)

Answer (score 0):

You've already got a web server running on port `80`. I see three viable choices:

1. Move `XAMPP's` version of Apache to a different port.
2. Move whatever `httpd` is running on port `80` to another port (or remove it)
3. Just install `lamp-server^` (a real production stack) and stop messing around with XAMPP (which is really just a toy for Windows developers)

Answer (score 0):

Do

~$ sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 stop

```
Stopping web server apache2 *
```

and then

$ sudo /opt/lampp/lampp start